# Can't boot Debian on AMD GPU

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, amd-radeon, linux-kernel

After installing Debian 9 Stable on my machine the boot process hangs at "fb: switching to amdgpudfb from EFI VGA".
From my research I think I need to update the kernel. How would I go about updating the kernel on an OS that doesnt boot?

Comment: Is it an on-board GPU or an Add-On card? If it is an add-on and there is an on-board too, remove the card while updating the kernel.

Comment: @Itai add-on. Rx 580. I dont have another one to put in to upgrade. Neither do I have onboard graphics. (Ryzen 1600)

Comment: Did you try booting into text mode? Usually if you use something like GRUB, you can interupt the normal boot process and set the init level to 3 which will stop before loading graphics. Then you can update your kernel package. I don't know how to do it with Debian (I'm running OpenSUSE) but that might be another question to ask here.

Comment: You may want to look and ask [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com) since that site is more specialized to Unix & Linux.

Comment: @Itai I dont have a de nor wm installed. So text mode is all there is aint it? Ill see what I can do